# Nattable grid representation for AND & OR operations

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am using Nattable framework to display and author data in grid UI using Eclipse RCP.
I have following expression:

```
Group1
    Value1 X
    Value2 X
    Value3
```

x - value is selected.

I have two use cases, system should do logical 'OR' for value1 and value2,
an another use case it should treat as logical 'AND'.

```
Use case 1 : Value1 && Value2  
Use case 2 : Value1 || Value2
```

How to represent/handle such data/use-cases in better way(UI gesture) in Nattable?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DirkFauth I have updated question, does that makes sense?

Comment: No. What are you trying to do? Filter? Grouping? Highlighting?